# Aligning right in android only work for last view added

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm trying to align right dynamically several ImageViews but only the last one is truly aligned.

In order to best understanding here is a picture:

[image]

The activity layout is set this way:

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Imagem"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

And in my code within this LinearLayout called Imagem I add more layouts in order to give me my final result, here is the code for adding a single line:

```
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.Imagem);
        LinearLayout llay = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout comandos = new LinearLayout(this);
        comandos.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        comandos.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        llay.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText(titulo);
        tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        tv.setTextSize(tv.getTextSize()*1.05f);
        TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
        tv2.setText(descricao);
        layout.addView(tv);
        layout.addView(llay);
        llay.addView(tv2);
        ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
        image.setImageDrawable(e);
        comandos.addView(image, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(Math.round(80*reducao),Math.round(60*reducao)));
        llay.addView(comandos, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,Gravity.RIGHT));
```

The way I add several images is just to keep creating new ImageViews and adding them to the "comandos" layout.

Is there any mistake that is making the correct alignment only to the last line?

Answer (score 0):

Horizontal LinearLayout does not support Gravity.RIGHT or LEFT, as it does not know what to do with the "Empty" space left between the views.

A very simple solution would be to set the TextView's weight to 1, so that it would "push" the image to the right and take up the empty space. Like so:

```
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.Imagem);
    LinearLayout llay = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout comandos = new LinearLayout(this);
    comandos.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    llay.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText(titulo);
    tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    tv.setTextSize(tv.getTextSize()*1.05f);
    TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
    tv2.setText(descricao);
    tv2.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1)); // setting weight to 1
    layout.addView(tv);
    layout.addView(llay);
    llay.addView(tv2);
    ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
    image.setImageDrawable(e);
    image.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(Math.round(80*reducao),Math.round(60*reducao)));
    comandos.addView(image);
    llay.addView(comandos, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Edit: I did not realise you were adding more images to comandos, fixed answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I updated my code with your corrections and it still the same image as I shown in my post, I didn't understood why the weight had to be in the text view, shouldn't it be in the comandos? EDIT: Actually just swiched to the old one and the current with the weight fix is even more to the left